# How do i add border in all four side of browser page

Tags: javascript

How do i add border in all four side of browser page no matter what browser, whatever resolution. Is there any such css or javascript code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want border around viewport you can try the following:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  body {position: fixed; top:0; left: 0; bottom: -5px; right: -5px; 
        border: 5px solid red;}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Depending on what you want exactly even better might be to use something as [YUI Layout Manager](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/layout/).

Comment: Nice one, I didn't consider setting left and right position at once  would be correct. Even though `bottom: 0; right: 0;` looks better, distances to the edge would be equal.

Answer (score 2):

Write the following lines in your CSS:

```
body {
  border-width: 5px; /* or what you want */
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red; /* or what you want */

  /* or use the short form: */
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , how do i always fit border-bottom to the bottom of the screen ?

Comment: Did you test it? Body has its margin and different size depending on content.

Comment: yes it worked, but it looks odd when border bottom height changes. How can i fix border bottom always stays at bottom ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<body style="margin:0px;margin-right:2px;margin-bottom:2px">
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;border:1px solid red;margin-right:-2px;margin-bottom:-2px">
    Stuff here
</div>
</body>
```

In my opinion it is better solution than `elektronikLexikon`'s, because height is always 100%.

EDIT: Height is fine now.

EDIT2: I like `jira`'s answer even more than mine ;)

PS. Request always the best answer, not that which meets only few requirements. I couldn't make it on time.